# Transaction with Spring and Mybatis

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, mybatis

I have this mapper-config.xml.There is the DAO and the BLM fot the Game class:

```
<bean id="DAOGame" class="it.certimeter.nagima.dao.game.DAOGame">
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="BLMGameTarget" class="it.certimeter.nagima.blm.game.BLMGame">
    <property name="daoGame" ref="DAOGame" />
</bean>
```

And the bean for the transaction:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" id="BLMGame">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
        <list>
            <value>it.certimeter.nagima.blm.game.IBLMGame</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
    </property>
    <property name="target">
        <ref bean="BLMGameTarget"/>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="saveGame">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, -it.fondsai.jeffs.core.exception.service.appl.JeffsServiceApplException</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <!-- <property name="anonymousAccess" value="true"/> -->
</bean>
```

But I have this error:
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [it.certimeter.nagima.blm.game.IBLMGame] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: BLMGameTarget,BLMGame

Where am I wrong??

Comment: You have two beans which implement the IBLMGame interface and spring doesn't know which to pick when wiring the beans together: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the issue with what Ben commented on.  I just ran into this myself the other day.

This issue brings a bad code smell with it, but if you want a workaround, I would suggest the following:

Go to where you @Autowire your IBLMGame instance.  In addition to the @Autowire annotation, you can provide a @Qualifier annotation and give a String value that represents the bean name you actually want wired in.

So for your case, it could look something like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("BLMGameTarget")  // you can substitute in "BLMGame" if that's the bean you want
IBLMGame iblmGame;
```

Comment: Thank you so much npm622. Why did you say there's a bad code smell with it?

Comment: "BLMGameTarget" and "BLMGame" sound very related -- almost as if one inherits or implements another.  I would venture to guess there would be a way to refactor your code so that only one of these concrete classes implement the interface you are auto-wiring.  Or you could get away with auto-wiring the more context-specific class as the field's type.